# How to access the EntityManager in a Phpunit Testcase in Symfony 5.4?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

on symfony 5.4, I'm testing on a rest api.
I always get errors when I try to access the entity manager

I followed this documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#functional-testing-of-a-doctrine-repository

here is my test code:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Repository\LocationRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DataTest extends WebTestCase     // WebTestCase  (not KernelTestCase)
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
    private LocationRepository $locationRepository;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
        $this->locationRepository = $this->entityManager->get(LocationRepository::class);
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();

        // doing this is recommended to avoid memory leaks
        $this->entityManager->close();
        $this->entityManager = null;
    }

    public function test401(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/api/locations');
        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $this->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(401);
    }
...
```

I get this error:

```
Testing App\Tests\DataTest
EEEE                                                                4 / 4 (100%)

There were 4 errors:

1) App\Tests\DataTest::test401
Error: Call to undefined method ContainerDyLAo2g\EntityManager_9a5be93::get()
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In `WebTestCase` you can access the entity manager like this

```
$this->entityManager = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class)
```

You can also check the documentation here https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test

Comment: Doesn't have to be `WebTestCase`, can just as easily be `KernelTestCase`. The former is more for sending HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `get()` on the EntityManagerInterface. Use the method `getRepository(string $className)` to fetch the repository:

```php
$this->locationRepository = $this->entityManager>getRepository(LocationEntity::class);
```